# Transfering strings instead of file using wifi direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have tried the google sample to transfer images between 2 phones as given [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F)

but how do I transfer strings instead of images?

Comment: can you post your code which you tried, what issue your are facing. Try this https://github.com/life0fun/wifi-direct-chat, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914774/android-passing-simple-string-over-wi-fi

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wi-fi-direct/uWpuOzHY6y0

Comment: Write the string to the `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

DeviceDetailFragment.java there is a method called copyFile which is having two params. InputStream and OutputStream, Inputstream provides you the files as byte stream, Instead that, convert your string to bytes and write it in outputstream in that `copyFile` method